# Why I am getting this warning message, does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd" in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I tried to assign a value to the Date (input). But I got the warning message and the Date field was also not getting updated with the assigned value.

**Warning message**: The specified value "Sun May 23 2021 16:06:23 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd".

How to assign a value (date) to the Date Input field in React using useState() hook?

Please let me know your suggestions. Thanks.

useState:

```
const todayDate = new Date();
const [ expenseDate, setExpenseDate ] = useState(todayDate);
```

JSX Part:

```
<label htmlFor="date-val">
    <input type="date" name="date-val" value={expenseDate} onChange={onDateChangeHandler} required />
</label>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to convert your Date in specific **`yyyy-mm-dd`** format

Try this

```
const todayDate = new Date(); 
const formatDate = todayDate.getDate() < 10 ? `0${todayDate.getDate()}`:todayDate.getDate();
const formatMonth = todayDate.getMonth() < 10 ? `0${todayDate.getMonth()}`: todayDate.getMonth();
const formattedDate = [todayDate.getFullYear(), formatMonth, formatDate].join('-');
const [expenseDate, setExpenseDate] = useState(formattedDate);
```

> The resulting value includes the year, month, and day, but not the
> time

For better understanding, go through [official documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date)

Comment: Thanks friend. Its working fine. I tried it earlier, but did not format it properly. I got it now. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Venkatesh_J if the answer is helpful for you. please accept/vote for it. Happy coding!.